In what order are GlobalPlatform applications selected for partial matches?
GlobalPlatform defines iterating over multiple partial AID matches via the two variants of the SELECT command, i.e. "SELECT [by command] [first or only occurrence]" and "SELECT [by command] [next occurrence]".
Am I missing something, or does the standard actually not specify the order in which the OPEN is to select/iterate applications in case of multiple matches?
If that's the case, is there any common expectation for what cards do practically? I could imagine them sorting either lexically, or possibly by application installation/instantiation order.

I don't remember a specific order. Annoying for sure and it is a weird feature anyway if you'd ask me. I'd assume lexicographical order, but that's just a guess. Problem with these kind of questions: if it is not defined then it is hard to come with an answer with an authoritative reference :P

While it would make me sad, I'd definitely accept "there is neither a standardized nor a de-facto standard order" as an answer if true :)
